# How to stop this loop

Tags: python

my code is

```
import keyboard

Test = False
number = 0

while True:
    while keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
        Test = True
    while keyboard.is_pressed('o'):
        Test = False
    while Test == True:
        number = number + 1
        print("example message " + str(number))
```

and why i can't stop this loop by pressing "O"?

Comment: Because your loop is using `True`, not `Test` - And the inner while loop is unnecessary

Comment: `break` when you want to.

Comment: In fact, all your inner while's should be if statements.

Answer (score 1):

Use `break` to stop while loop

```
import keyboard

Test = False
number = 0

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
        Test = True
    if keyboard.is_pressed('o'):
        Test = False
        break
    if Test:
        number = number + 1
        print("example message " + str(number))
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write it like this

```
import keyboard

Test = False
number = 0

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
        Test = True
        break
    if keyboard.is_pressed('o'):
        Test = False
        break

if Test == True:
    number = number + 1
    print("example message " + str(number))
```

Comment: Your code will only execute one time, so this answer wont work. Also according to your answer, you do not need `while` loop since it will execute only 1 time.

Comment: yes i understand it just minutes after posting it so a mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can use break inside the while loop to stop looping the code.

```
import keyboard

Test = False
number = 0

while True:
    while keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
        Test = True
    while keyboard.is_pressed('o'):
        Test = False
        break
    if Test == True:
        number = number + 1
        print("example message " + str(number))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import keyboard

Test = False
number = 0

while True:

    while keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
        Test = True
    while keyboard.is_pressed('o'):
        Test = False
    if Test:
        number = number + 1
        print("example message " + str(number))
```